# Concrete5.7 Routing Register Function

Tags: php, api, concrete5

I'm new to Concrete5. I've been trying the suggestion outlined in the question below:

[concrete5 website API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336561/concrete5-website-api)

I have encountered some things (an inconsistency and a bug)

1. The Route class didn't have the Register function so I switched to Router instead.
2. After that, I get the error "Call to a member function add() on null". I suppose it's because Register can accept up to 4 parameters but I'm only passing 2. Then at the end of the function, there's this:

   ```php
   $this->collection->add($rtHandle, $route);
   ```

I'm guessing $rtHandle is empty so it throws an exception. What value should I pass to it so the registration will go through?

Comment: That error is happening because `$this->collection` is null. You probably want to learn some basics about PHP and OOP before you get too much farther